# Django не коммитит save при использовании Multiple Database

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Есть две базы данных: `default` и `mart`. БД postgreSQL.
Есть следующие строки:

```
site_user = SiteUser.objects.using('mart').get(id=1)
site_user.save(using='default', force_insert=True)
site_user = SiteUser.objects.using('default').get(id=1)
```

На третьей строчке вылетает ошибка, что такой `site_user` не найден. Хотя вторая строчка (если верить [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/multi-db/)) должна гарантировать, что такой `site_user` создался в базе `default` (иначе вылетит ошибка).

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет, у меня Django 1.7.3. Я создал БД mart и попытался воспроизвести

```
In [1]: from products.models import Color

In [3]: Color.objects.using('mart').count()
Out[3]: 0

In [2]: Color.objects.using('default').count()
Out[2]: 16

In [3]: c = Color.objects.using('default').get(pk=1)

In [4]: c.save(using='mart', force_insert=True)

In [5]: Color.objects.using('mart').get(pk=1)
Out[5]: <Color: Black>

In [6]: Color.objects.using('mart').count()
Out[6]: 1
```

но у меня не воспроизводится ваша проблема. Какая у вас версия Django? И покажите опции DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS'], если есть

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Действительно ошибки никакой нет, оказалось коллега сделал опечатку при наследовании save (force_insert всегда равнялся False), а я этого не заметил(